# vboxmanage dhcpserver add but client can't get DHCP ip

Tags: virtualbox

This is the command I use in host OS, unfortunately guest OS still can't get the DHCP ip.

Both OS are running in Linux.

```
wolf@linux:~$ vboxmanage dhcpserver add --network=malfoy --server-ip=10.38.1.1 --lower-ip=10.38.1.110 --upper-ip=10.38.1.120 --netmask=255.255.255.0 --enable
wolf@linux:~$
```

**Verification**

```
wolf@linux:~$ vboxmanage list dhcpservers
NetworkName:    malfoy
Dhcpd IP:       10.38.1.1
LowerIPAddress: 10.38.1.110
UpperIPAddress: 10.38.1.120
NetworkMask:    255.255.255.0
Enabled:        Yes
Global Configuration:
    minLeaseTime:     default
    defaultLeaseTime: default
    maxLeaseTime:     default
    Forced options:   None
    Suppressed opts.: None
        1/legacy: 255.255.255.0
Groups:               None
Individual Configs:   None
wolf@linux:~$
```

**Guest OS**

```
guestOS$ ip a s enp0s3
2: enp0s3: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 08:00:27:aa:aa:aa brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
guestOS$ 

guestOS$ sudo dhclient enp0s3 -v
Internet Systems Consortium DHCP Client 4.4.1
Copyright 2004-2018 Internet Systems Consortium.
All rights reserved.
For info, please visit https://www.isc.org/software/dhcp/

Listening on LPF/enp0s3/08:00:27:aa:aa:aa
Sending on   LPF/enp0s3/08:00:27:aa:aa:aa
Sending on   Socket/fallback
DHCPDISCOVER on enp0s3 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 3 (xid=0xc1337)
DHCPDISCOVER on enp0s3 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 7 (xid=0xc1337)
DHCPDISCOVER on enp0s3 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 10 (xid=0xc1337)
...
DHCPDISCOVER on enp0s3 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 8 (xid=0xc1337)
DHCPDISCOVER on enp0s3 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 11 (xid=0xc1337)
DHCPDISCOVER on enp0s3 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 14 (xid=0xc1337)
No DHCPOFFERS received.
No working leases in persistent database - sleeping.
guestOS$
```

Reference:

https://progmar.net.pl/en/knowledge-base/virtualbox-adding-dhcp-server

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mvsiuLzpx2E

How do I troubleshoot this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might find the following question weird, but I've seen it solved most of the issues in VirtualBox.

1. Have you installed VirtualBox Guest Additions?
2. Have you rebooted the guest OS
3. Have you rebooted the host OS

Comment: I did the 1st 2, it didn't resolve the issue. But when I reboot the host OS, the guest OS get the DHCP ip as expected. Thanks